# Xpages radio group border

Tags: border, xpages, radio-group

I have a simple radio button group (Gender). In edit mode, it has a thin gray/silver border around the button group (IE, Firefox). It is inside the cell of a table, which is inside a panel embedded in another panel on an Xpage. I'm using no themes or anything. I've tried for days using every suggestion I could find in SO and other sites, but nothing is working. I've also tried a blank Xpage and put just the radio group on it, and it still has the border. This must be an issue that every xpage developer sees. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this border?

```
<xp:table style="width:100.0%; border-bottom:1px solid blue;margin-bottom:20.0px">
<xp:tr>
<xp:td styleClass="Q1" align="left">What is your gender?
</xp:td>
</xp:tr>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td style="padding-left:40.0px" align="left">
<xp:radioGroup id="Feeding" styleClass="A2" value="#{document1.Gender}">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female">
</xp:selectItem>
</xp:radioGroup></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First alternative: Use style like:

```
...
<xp:radioGroup id="Feeding" styleClass="A2" style="border:0px;" value="#{document1.Gender}">
...
```

Second alternative: Add the following rule into your CSS:

```
fieldset.A2 {
    border: 0 none;
}
```